# Which is best way to analyse relationship - R

Tags: r

I am currently working on my thesis about video-game quality/innovation and I am stuck on how to analyse a given relationship. I am using R.

I want to run an analyses where I can see if a gaming studio releases less/more novel innovative IP post-acquisiton. My hypothesis states "Target companies release less novel content post-merger". I ran a linear regression, however, this does not show me (conclusevely) if independent vs. acquired studios release less/more IP.

Which form analysis is best suited for this case? Sample of my data-set below. All tips appreciated, thank you!

```
structure(list(Game_name = c("Neon Chrome", "Sparkle 2", "Frostpunk", 
"Anomaly 2", "Double Cross", "King's Bounty II"), Publisher = c("10tons 
Entertainment, 
10tons", 
"10tons Ltd, 10tons", "11 Bit Studios", "11 Bit Studios", "13AM Games", 
"1C Entertainment, Prime Matter"), Metacritic_rating = c(63, 
66, 87, 74, 78, 57), Exclusive = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0), Innovative = c(1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0), Independant_studio = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Acquired_studio = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Internally_developed = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

#Example linear model
lrmC <- Innovative ~ Independant_studio + 
Acquired_studio + Internally_developed
```

Comment: In my eyes this is really a question about statistics, and not about computers.  The topic to read up about would be statistical hypothesis tests.  My guess is that you'll need more data before you get meaningful results.

Comment: @jochen I have 2980 entries in my data-set, this is only a dput(head(() output

Comment: If `Innovative` is a binary variable, then a logistic regression would be the obvious choice, i.e. `glm(lrmC, data = df, family = binomial)`